# Multiple nested dynamic Formgroups in multiple nested tabs

Tags: angular, nested-forms, dynamic-forms, angular11

I need some help and I'm getting nuts by doing this. i have a parentForm calls disclosureForm: In this disclosureForm there could be an amount of n subforms called household. The Amount of subforms depends on the amount of Tabs. Each houseHold Tab could have an amount of n on different subforms also depending on the amount of tabs for example: one household could have an amount of n applicants each applicant  does have his own subtab which includes his own form.

The structure should be like the following example.

```
disclosureForm: {
  household_1:{
    applicant_1: {
      name: doe,
      firstName: john,
      birthdate: ......
    },
    applicant_2: {
      name: doe,
      firstName: jane,
      birthdate: ......
    }
  },
  household_2: {
    applicant_1: {
      name: page,
      firstName: jimmy,
      birthdate: .....
    }

  }

}
```

My HTML structure looks like:

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="haushaltSelected.value">
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of haushaltTabs; let haushaltTabindex = index" [label]="tab">             
            <form [formGroup]="disclosureForm">
            <div @fadeInUp class="card overflow-hidden">
                <mat-vertical-stepper #verticalStepper="matVerticalStepper" [linear]="true">
                    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
                        <mat-icon [icIcon]="icDoneAll"></mat-icon>
                    </ng-template>
            
                    <ng-template matStepperIcon="done">
                    <mat-icon [icIcon]="icDoneAll"></mat-icon>
                    </ng-template>
            
                    <mat-step [stepControl]="applicantForm">
                        
                            <ng-template matStepLabel>Personal Data</ng-template>

                            <div class="title m-0">Applicant Information</div>
                            <div class="subheading-1">Please fill the Form with your personal data.</div>

                            <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="applicantSelected.value">
                                <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of applicantTabs; let index = index" [label]="tab">
                                    <div [formGroup]="applicantForm">
                                        
                                        <div class="mt-4" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="8px">

                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">
                                    
                                                <mat-radio-group class="mb-4" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="16px" formControlName="personTitle">
                                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngFor="let title of titles">
                                                        <mat-radio-button color="primary" [id]="title" [value]="title">{{ title }}</mat-radio-button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </mat-radio-group>
                                    
                                                <mat-radio-group class="ml-8" fxLayout="row" formControlName="academicTitle" fxLayoutGap="16px">
                                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline" *ngFor="let acadmeic of academicTitles">
                                                        <mat-checkbox color="primary" type="checkbox" [id]="acadmeic">{{acadmeic}}</mat-checkbox>
                                                    </div>    
                                                </mat-radio-group>
                                    
                                            </div>
                                    
                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="auto">
                                                    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="name" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihren Nachnamen ein.</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="auto">
                                                    <mat-label>Vorname</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="firstName" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie alle Ihren Vornamen gemäß Ausweis ein.</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                            </div>
                                        
                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">                                                 
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="49.2%">
                                                    <mat-label>E-Mail</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="email" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Email Adresse in folgendem Format an: example@example.com</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>

                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="49.2%">
                                                    <mat-label>E-Mail wiederholen</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="confirmEmail" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte wiederholen Sie die zuvor eingegebene Email Adresse</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                            </div>                                
                                        
                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row"  fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">

                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                    <mat-label>Geburtsdatum</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="birthDate" [matDatepicker]="datepickerRef" matInput>
                                                    <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="datepickerRef" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                                    <mat-datepicker #datepickerRef></mat-datepicker>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie ihr Geburtsdatum an. Ein Klick auf das Icon öffnet die Datumsauswahl.</mat-hint>
                                                  </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                    <mat-label>Geburtsort</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="cityOfBirth" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihren Geburtsort ein.</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                            </div>  
                                            
                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">
                                                
                                                <div fxFlex="auto" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="12px">
                                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="75%">
                                                        <mat-label>Straße</mat-label>
                                                        <input formControlName="address" matInput required>
                                                        <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Straße an.</mat-hint>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="25%">
                                                        <mat-label>Nr.</mat-label>
                                                        <input formControlName="houseNumber" matInput required>
                                                        <mat-hint>Hausnummer</mat-hint>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                </div>
                                        
                                                <div fxFlex="auto" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="12px">
                                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="25%">
                                                        <mat-label>PLZ</mat-label>
                                                        <input formControlName="postalCode" matInput required>
                                                        <mat-hint>Postleitzahl</mat-hint>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="75%">
                                                        <mat-label>Ort</mat-label>
                                                        <input formControlName="city" matInput required>
                                                        <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihren Wohnort an.</mat-hint>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                </div>
                                        
                                            </div>  
                                        
                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="auto">
                                                    <mat-label>Wohnhaft seit</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="residentSince" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie an seit wann sie an oben genannter Adresse wohnen.</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="auto">
                                                    <mat-label>Steuer ID</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="taxNo" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Steueridentifikationsnummer an.</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                            </div>
                                        
                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row"  fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">
                                                
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                    <mat-label>Familienstand</mat-label>
                                                        <mat-select formControlName="familyStatus" required>
                                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of familyStatus" [value]="option">{{ option }}</mat-option>
                                                        </mat-select>
                                                        <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihren Familienstand an</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                    <mat-label>Staatsangehörigkeit</mat-label>
                                                        <mat-select formControlName="nationality" required>
                                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of nationality" [value]="option">{{ option }}</mat-option>
                                                        </mat-select>
                                                        <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Nationalität an</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                            </div>  
                                        
                                            <hr class="mt-4">
                                            <div class="subheading-1">Bitte geben Sie Informationen zu Ihrem Einkommen und Ihrer Beschäftigung an.</div>
                                        
                                            <div class="mt-4" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row"  fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">
                                                
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                    <mat-label>Art der Beschäftigung</mat-label>
                                                    <mat-select formControlName="employment" required>
                                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of employmentMode" [value]="option">{{ option }}</mat-option>
                                                    </mat-select>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Beschftigungsart an</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                    <mat-label>Einkommen</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="revenues" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihr monatliches Nettoeinkommen an.</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                            </div> 
                                        
                                            <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutGap="8px" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="24px">
                                                
                                                <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                    <mat-label>Sozialversicherungsnummer</mat-label>
                                                    <input formControlName="nationalInsuranceNumber" matInput required>
                                                    <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihre Sozialversicherungsnummer an</mat-hint>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                <div fxFlex="50%" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="12px">
                                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                        <mat-label>Einkommen Vorjahr</mat-label>
                                                        <input formControlName="lastYearRevenue" matInput required>
                                                        <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihr Vorjahreseinkommen an.</mat-hint>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                        
                                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%">
                                                        <mat-label>Einkommen aktuelles Jahr</mat-label>
                                                        <input formControlName="currentYearRevenue" matInput required>
                                                        <mat-hint>Bitte geben Sie Ihr aktuelles Jahreseinkommen an.</mat-hint>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                </div>
                                        
                                            </div>                                          
                                            
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <hr class="mt-6"> 
                                    </div>
                                </mat-tab>                                
                            </mat-tab-group>
                            
                
                            
                
                            <div class="actions mt-4" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
                                
                                <button (click)="addPerson(haushaltTabindex)" color="primary" mat-button type="button">weitere Person hinzufügen</button>
                                <button (click)="verticalStepper.reset()" [disabled]="" color="primary"
                                        mat-button
                                        type="button">Zurücksetzen
                                </button>
                                <button [disabled]="" color="primary" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>
                                    Weiter
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        
                    </mat-step>
            
                    <mat-step [stepControl]="">
                        <form>
                            <ng-template matStepLabel>Vermögen</ng-template>
                
                            <div class="title m-0">Vermögen</div>
                            <div class="subheading-1">Geben Sie hier Ihre Vermögenswerte an.</div>
                
                           
                
                            <div class="actions" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
                            <button color="primary" mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">PREVIOUS</button>
                            <button [disabled]="" color="primary" mat-raised-button matStepperNext>
                                NEXT
                            </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </mat-step>
            
                    <mat-step [stepControl]="">
                    <form [formGroup]="">
                        <ng-template matStepLabel>Einnahmen</ng-template>
            
                        <div class="title m-0">You're almost there!</div>
                        <div class="subheading-1">To finish registration, accept our terms of service and click on "Create Account".
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="mt-4" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="8px">
                        <mat-checkbox class="checkbox" formControlName="terms">
                            I agree to the terms of service and the usual stuff. *
                        </mat-checkbox>
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="actions" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
                        <button color="primary" mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">PREVIOUS</button>
                        <button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="" color="primary" mat-raised-button
                                matStepperNext>
                            CREATE ACCOUNT
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            
                    </mat-step>
                </mat-vertical-stepper>
            </div>
        </form>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

How can I achieve that every form in his own tab got an own reference to a Formgroup, which are dynamically generated? I've tried a lot of tutorials, but they're always in one Formgroup and not multiple forms in their in own Tabs. I'm stuck :(